# Ubuntu guest in VMWare stucks before login

Tags: 18.04, vmware

I have Ubuntu 18.04 installed on my VMWare Fusion for months without any issues. After recent update through Software Updater, it required a restart.

Currently when I'm trying to load my Ubuntu it is stuck on the purple screen just before the login prompt.

I tried to use `nomodeset` in GRUB and I'm getting to the login screen but black screen after.

How can I make my virtual machine boot up successfully to the desktop?

Comment: In the `vmlinuz` line in the grub remove `quiet` and `splash` before booting and you'll see the boot sequence (Sorry don't have enough rep to comment).

Comment: The last line after it stuck: started user manager for uid 121. And no errors at the boot...

Comment: Could you a take a photo of  your screen at that time. Also try to boot in recovery mode. Drop to a root shell and check your free disk space with `df -h` for instance.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same exact problem with Ubuntu 18.04.2 and VMware Fusion (both 10.1.5 and 11.1.0) and I found the solution here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/426235/how-to-solve-stopping-user-manager-for-uid-121-error-after-installing-nvidia-d

I went into recovery mode and installed lightdm:

```
sudo apt install lightdm
```

and switched from gdm3 to lightdm by running:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

After rebooting everything works fine.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much, you are lifesaver!!!

Comment: You are welcome!!! ;-)

Comment: Thanks so much. This saved me many hours of searching. Issue occurred after apt-get update/dist-upgrade in my Ubuntu VM using VMWare Workstation 14. Lightdm was already installed but not set as default for me.

Answer (score 0):

Having the same exact problem here with 18.04 on Oraclebox after the most recent update.  Rolled back to the previous kernel and still no joy.  Going into recovery and booting DOES bring up the desktop but subsequent reboots still give me the purple screen of death.  This screams display issue to me.

Switched my Graphics controller from VMSVGA to VboxVGA is now giving me the login screen.  Not sure VMWare options are available for your display but you may want to try switching things around to see if it makes any difference.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running on VMWare Workstation 15 Pro. Same problem when I went from 18.04.1 and allowed it to update. I'm a noob with Ubuntu so I had no clue what to do.

I created a new 18.04.1 VM and it died the same way when I updated.

Creating an 18.04.2 VM seems to work ok, but I am unable to load a gcc with a non experimental version of filesystem.h. I don't know how I got that working on 18.04.1.

I'm working fine now with 19.04, but would like to report this bug to help out the Ubuntu team.(As a software engineer, I appreciate feedback on issues.) However the bug reporting tool requires Ubuntu to be running from what I can tell.

Any ideas on how to report this bug?